# Elasticsearch java high level client group by and max

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, group-by

I am using Scala 2.12 and Elasticsearch 6.5. Using the high level java client to query the ES.

Required Data is as E.g. Simple example of Documents has 2 sets of data (published 2 times) with different id and timestamp.

id: id_123 and id_234 (Theese are 2 different ids of required documents) and timestamp(representation only) 10 AM (for id_123) and 11 AM (for id_234).
So I just need those documents which are latest among these i.e. 11 AM one.

I have some filter conditions and then need to group on field1 and take the max of field2 (which is timestamp).

```
val searchRequest = new SearchRequest("index_name")
val searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder()

val qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
      .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("myfield.date", "2019-07-02"))
      .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("myfield.data", "1111"))
      .must(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
        .should(QueryBuilders.regexpQuery("myOtherFieldId", "myregex1"))
        .should(QueryBuilders.regexpQuery("myOtherFieldId", "myregex2"))
      )

val myAgg = AggregationBuilders.terms("group_by_Id").field("field1.Id").subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.max("timestamp").field("field1.timeStamp"))

searchSourceBuilder.query(qb)
searchSourceBuilder.aggregation(myAgg)
searchSourceBuilder.size(1000)

searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder)

val searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT)
```

Basically, all works good if I do not use the aggregation.

When I use the aggregation, I am getting the following error:

```
ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=Expected numeric type on field [field1.timeStamp], but got [keyword]]]
```

So what am I missing here?
I am basically looking for SQL-like query, which has fileter (where, AND/OR clause) and then group by a field (Id) and take documents only where timeStamp is max.

**UPDATE:**

I tried the above query in cURL via command prompt and get the same error when using "max" on aggregaation.

```
{
  "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": { "myfield.date" : "2019-07-02" }
                },
                {
                    "match": { "myfield.data" : "1111" }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "regexp": { "myOtherFieldId": "myregex1" }
                            },
                            {
                                "regexp": { "myOtherFieldId": "myregex2" }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "NAME" : {
            "terms": { 
                "field": "field1.Id"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "NAME": {
                    "max" : {
                        "field": "field1.timeStamp"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "size": "10000"
}
```

I am getting the same error.

I tried to check the mappings of the index.
It is showing as keyword. So how to do max on such fields?

Adding the relevant mappings:

```
{"index_name":{"mappings":{"data":{"dynamic_templates":[{"boolean_as_keyword":{"match":"*","match_mapping_type":"boolean","mapping":{"ignore_above":256,"type":"keyword"}}},{"double_as_keyword":{"match":"*","match_mapping_type":"double","mapping":{"ignore_above":256,"type":"keyword"}}},{"long_as_keyword":{"match":"*","match_mapping_type":"long","mapping":{"ignore_above":256,"type":"keyword"}}},{"string_as_keyword":{"match":"*","match_mapping_type":"string","mapping":{"ignore_above":256,"type":"keyword"}}}],"date_detection":false,"properties":{"header":{"properties":{"Id":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256},"otherId":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256},"someKey":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256},"dataType":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256},"processing":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256},"otherKey":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256},"sender":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256},"receiver":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256},"system":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256},"timeStamp":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}}}}}}
```

**UPDATE2:**

I think I need to aggregate (timeStamp) on keyword.

Please note that timeStamp is a subfield i.e. under field1. So below syntax for keyword doesn't seem to work or I am missing something else.

```
"aggs": {
            "NAME" : {
                "terms": { 
                    "field": "field1.Id"
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "NAME": {
                        "max" : {
                            "field": "field1.timeStamp.keyword"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

It fails now saying:

```
"Invalid aggregator order path [field1.timeStamp]. Unknown aggregation [field1]"
```

Comment: Please add the complete mapping of the index.

Comment: I added the relevant mappings and edited the question above.